# Selectable jqueryui rerordering html tag content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have applied jquery ui selectable  on a div.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="selectable">
    <p>xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz <b>ABC </b> <i> 124</i> <span>asdfasdf</span></p>
    <p>xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz <b>ABC </b> <i> 124</i> <span>asdfasdf</span></p>
    <div>xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz <i> 124</i> <span>asdfasdf</span><ul><li>=====</li><li>+++++++</li></ul></div>
</div>
```

jQuery/Javacript Code:

```
$('#selectable').selectable();
```

but what's happening is that when i select then html change means order of `p` tag, `b` tag, `i` tag changes some time as dragging functionality happening.

Any Help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectable").click(function (event) {
         $("p, b, i, span, div, ul, li", this)
        .removeClass("selected")
        .filter(event.target)
        .addClass("selected");
    });
});
```

`i`, `span` and `div` are in line therefore can not be separated.

```
.selected{
    color: white;
    background-color: #F39814;
}
```